# Does the Open CTI adapter require any additional licensing?

Tags: licenses

I'm under the impression that the Open CTI adapter can be used in both the Service Cloud Service Console and the standard UI (in the side bar) at no additional cost?  i.e. a Service Cloud license is not required.

Does any one know?

Comment: Finding this documentation, the answer appears to be 'no, you don't' or rather 'No, SF documentation does not mention it'

Comment: To be able to use the Service Cloud Console, you need the Service Cloud Feature license. (Service Cloud user should be checked at a User level) However use of the open CTI adapter can be used irrespective. If you don't have a Service Cloud feature license, you can use it in the sales cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't require additional licenses.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party here, but wanted to clarify this issue for those who come searching.

No OpenCTI feature licenses are required, but here are a few things to keep in mind. CTI can pop a new record, or a record detail page that the Force.com license cannot access (ie. Leads). The same holds true for Salesforce Platform Licenses that do not have access to Opportunities/Quotes/etc. Also, Partner Community licenses can access CTI too.

That all said, some CTI vendors are not native to Salesforce, and required Enteprise level licenses to Salesforce to pull data using the REST API and then dial on their platform.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paul, no Open CTI feature licenses are required. However, a few CTI vendors that aren't native to salesforce needs enterprise level licenses.